# Can a school find my personal computer if I'm on their wifi?

Tags: wifi, anonymity

I know that they can find my search history on their wifi and some websites (reddit etc) are blocked, but will they be able to know it was my computer specifically?

Comment: In most cases they can because there is a captive portal requiring you to enter a username or ID when you get on the WiFi.  If not, they can also check for the NetBIOS name of the computer -- often "John Doe's MacBook Pro."  Lacking these two features, probably not.

Comment: This will depend entirely on how they set up their wifi access. Also, your title question and the question in the body of your post are different. Are you asking about "finding" your computer or tying traffic to your computer? Physically finding your computer will be difficult if not impossible. Tying traffic to your computer can be very easy (even if you use a VPN). Hiding specific traffic to specific sites is another question entirely. Can you clarify what you are asking about?

Comment: As an expert on how an entire nation's university and college sectors deploy and track wifi on all campuses in the country, I can definitively say, "it depends". The answers below are possible in some cases, but not in others. Some schools require logging in, some require endpoint agents, some require certificates to be installed, some use proxies. Some measures could be broken by changing your MAC, others would not. Some measures could be defeated by VPNs, some would not. We cannot tell you what's possible in *your* school.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all of your internet traffic can be tied directly to your computer.

Can they identify you personally? Your Wi-Fi adapter communicated to their network using its own MAC address, so they can tie all the activity coming from that MAC together. So any one thing you did online that identified you personally, such as logging in or entering your email address, could be used to link your identity to your entire browsing history.

A different question is whether or not they are monitoring and/or recording your traffic. Most schools will route your traffic through a filtering proxy of some sort; these proxies may provide a report of violations to your school.

They may normally not trace your connections, but if they discover you are using their connection for something illicit, they will likely examine their logs more carefully for evidence of who the computer belongs to. But those are guesses as to how they may react; your results may vary.

If you are concerned, there may be some things you can do.

If you did not install a certificate provided to you by your school, then as long as you connect only to https sites, they will only be able to see what server you connected to, and how much data you exchanged, but not the exact contents of the data. If you did install a certificate, they can intercept everything you are doing.

For better protection you can use a VPN tunnel, which will protect all of your traffic from interception.

Comment: Unless of course the proxy that the school is using is an SSL Forwarding proxy with an enterprise CA cert, then you're just screwed.

Comment: @xorist , that is what I discussed in the next-to-last paragraph,  “if you did not install a certificate provided by your school “...  An SSL/TLS intercepting proxy only works if your browser trusts the certificate of the key used to re-encrypt the pages. Those certificates are usually installed by the administrators, but only on school-owned/enterprise-owned equipment. Such certs aren’t present on your own laptop—unless you deliberately install one.

Comment: I thought that some professional products out there used wildcard certificates from CAs that typically come pre-trusted with your browser. If that's the case, then you're not going to have to install a certificate from the admin for them to sniff your SSL traffic.

Comment: @xorist, no CA would ever allow their authority to be misused in that way! It would violate every rule of the CA/B forum https://cabforum.org/ and get their certs removed from every browser. It would be an instant death sentence for their business.  No, all legit intercepting proxies require the cooperation of the browser admins. This is even true for the malware proxies like Superfish, which required their sleazy cert to be installed in the browser.

Comment: Ah well, I must've read something of a violation to that rule somewhere, then.