# Can my school see my browsing history while on campus?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, wifi

I'm a bit paranoid right now about what my school can and can't see on my device. My school has a BYOD policy which means that I bring my own device to work. I am logged in using my personal account almost all the time though and I recently did an incognito search.

I want to know whether or not my school could see what I searched when I opened that browser.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is related to security, Simple answer is any plain text messages which you are and sending and receiving can read. Additionally school can detect what site you are accessing rather reading what you are doing on site. VPN will solve that particular issue.

Comment: There is too much unknown with your setup, especially if you are using the campus network, if SSL interception is done, if you  have installed some software or made special security changes to use the network etc. But there are [several similar searches here on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+what+can+my+school+see) which also have more detailed about the specific setup.  Please study these questions first and if none fits your problem please provide a more specific description of your setup.

Comment: @Infra So, I decided to damage a document to get an extension for a project. Will the school be able to see those messages or will they just know that I accessed that website at a specific time? 

Besides this, can my school know what I download on their network to my device?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I use a Surface Laptop 3 with nothing special besides having Norton browsing protection and uBlock Origin for an adblocker. Does this mean that they can see what websites I accessed and when as well as what I download on their network?

Comment: @JohnathonKeys: Again, look at the other questions first. The answers there like apply to your one too or at least help you to find out which details need to be provided for a better question. If you don't find the right answers please make clear by editing the question how your one differs from the existing ones so that one provide a more focused answer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have looked at this thread in particular: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195034/can-a-school-find-my-personal-computer-if-im-on-their-wifi and it says: 

"If you did not install a certificate provided to you by your school, then as long as you connect only to https sites, they will only be able to see what server you connected to, and how much data you exchanged, but not the exact contents of the data. If you did install a certificate, they can intercept everything you are doing."

How do I know whether or not my school installed a certificate on my device?

Comment: Usually, you do the installing.

Comment: @schroeder Is it an automatic process that happens in the background or do I manually have to install the certificate?

Comment: You manually install